# How do I convert a SOAP to JSON?

Tags: php, json, xml, soap

I have a soap file that i am trying to convert to JSON. I have realised that I can use `simplexml_load_string` without namespaces as below

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($soap_string);
$json = json_encode($xml);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $json;
```

My response xml below has namespaces and therefore throws errors when i try using `simplexml_load_string`.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <res:ResultMsg xmlns:res="http://api-v1.gen.mm.vodafone.com/mminterface/result">
                <![CDATA[
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <Result xmlns="http://api-v1.gen.mm.vodafone.com/mminterface/result">
                   <ResultType>0</ResultType>
                   <ResultCode>0</ResultCode>
                   <ResultDesc>The service request has been accepted successfully.</ResultDesc>
                   <OriginatorConversationID>555010_jYJlV0MP3y</OriginatorConversationID>
                   <ConversationID>20170705_00007d59ab9111033601</ConversationID>
                   <TransactionID>LG51195MWH</TransactionID>
                   <ResultParameters>
                      <ResultParameter>
                         <Key>TransactionAmount</Key>
                         <Value>100</Value>
                      </ResultParameter>
                      <ResultParameter>
                         <Key>TransactionReceipt</Key>
                         <Value>LG51195MWH</Value>
                      </ResultParameter>
                      <ResultParameter>
                         <Key>B2CRecipientIsRegisteredCustomer</Key>
                         <Value>Y</Value>
                      </ResultParameter>
                      <ResultParameter>
                         <Key>B2CChargesPaidAccountAvailableFunds</Key>
                         <Value>-55.00</Value>
                      </ResultParameter>
                      <ResultParameter>
                         <Key>ReceiverPartyPublicName</Key>
                         <Value>254713171292 - test test</Value>
                      </ResultParameter>
                      <ResultParameter>
                         <Key>TransactionCompletedDateTime</Key>
                         <Value>05.07.2017 08:27:38</Value>
                      </ResultParameter>
                      <ResultParameter>
                         <Key>B2CUtilityAccountAvailableFunds</Key>
                         <Value>32526.00</Value>
                      </ResultParameter>
                      <ResultParameter>
                         <Key>B2CWorkingAccountAvailableFunds</Key>
                         <Value>541703.00</Value>
                      </ResultParameter>
                   </ResultParameters>
                   <ReferenceData>
                      <ReferenceItem>
                         <Key>QueueTimeoutURL</Key>
                         <Value>https://localhost:443/pay/timeout.php</Value>
                      </ReferenceItem>
                   </ReferenceData>
                </Result>
                ]]>
            </res:ResultMsg>
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

How do I take out the envelope parts from the soap response above so that I can remain with only the xml part that I can easily store in variable and covert it to json using `simplexml_load_string`?

Comment: Use a SOAP Api (ext/soap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The json can not be parsed because your xml file contains "**xml
>   namespace**". With Regex you can parse the json by selecting the
>   "**Result**" tag (Basic way).
>
> *If you can test it, you can edit the regex pattern you need.*

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$soap_string = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <res:ResultMsg xmlns:res="http://api-v1.gen.mm.vodafone.com/mminterface/result">
            <![CDATA[
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <Result xmlns="http://api-v1.gen.mm.vodafone.com/mminterface/result">
               <ResultType>0</ResultType>
               <ResultCode>0</ResultCode>
               <ResultDesc>The service request has been accepted successfully.</ResultDesc>
               <OriginatorConversationID>555010_jYJlV0MP3y</OriginatorConversationID>
               <ConversationID>20170705_00007d59ab9111033601</ConversationID>
               <TransactionID>LG51195MWH</TransactionID>
               <ResultParameters>
                  <ResultParameter>
                     <Key>TransactionAmount</Key>
                     <Value>100</Value>
                  </ResultParameter>
                  <ResultParameter>
                     <Key>TransactionReceipt</Key>
                     <Value>LG51195MWH</Value>
                  </ResultParameter>
                  <ResultParameter>
                     <Key>B2CRecipientIsRegisteredCustomer</Key>
                     <Value>Y</Value>
                  </ResultParameter>
                  <ResultParameter>
                     <Key>B2CChargesPaidAccountAvailableFunds</Key>
                     <Value>-55.00</Value>
                  </ResultParameter>
                  <ResultParameter>
                     <Key>ReceiverPartyPublicName</Key>
                     <Value>254713171292 - test test</Value>
                  </ResultParameter>
                  <ResultParameter>
                     <Key>TransactionCompletedDateTime</Key>
                     <Value>05.07.2017 08:27:38</Value>
                  </ResultParameter>
                  <ResultParameter>
                     <Key>B2CUtilityAccountAvailableFunds</Key>
                     <Value>32526.00</Value>
                  </ResultParameter>
                  <ResultParameter>
                     <Key>B2CWorkingAccountAvailableFunds</Key>
                     <Value>541703.00</Value>
                  </ResultParameter>
               </ResultParameters>
               <ReferenceData>
                  <ReferenceItem>
                     <Key>QueueTimeoutURL</Key>
                     <Value>https://localhost:443/pay/timeout.php</Value>
                  </ReferenceItem>
               </ReferenceData>
            </Result>
            ]]>
        </res:ResultMsg>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';

//file_get_contents("http://localhost:24563/soap_string.xml"); // test xml url :) remove this comment
$pattern = "(<Result(.+)>[\s\S]*?<\/Result>)";
preg_match_all($pattern, $soap_string, $matches);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($matches[0][0]);
echo json_encode($xml);
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried this yourself??  My problem isnt the function converting the xml to json but the xml itself.  Want to strip out 
`<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <res:ResultMsg xmlns:res="http://api-v1.gen.mm.vodafone.com/mminterface/result">
                <![CDATA[`

and

`]]>
            </res:ResultMsg>
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>`